# Help understand this set theoretic equations regarding Natural Numbers

Tags: limits, elementary-set-theory

I have $\color{fuchsia}2$ problems here :

$\mathbb N$- Set of all natural numbers

$\Lambda=\{\lambda_n\}_n$ is a **non-decreasing**  sequence of natural numbers such that $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_{n+1}\le \lambda_n +1.$

$I_n=[n-\lambda_n+1,n]$

Given that $\lim_n {\lambda_n\over n}=1.$

$D$ is a given condition that some natural numbers may satisfy , others may not.

Then for any $\delta \gt 0$, we can find a $m\in \mathbb N$, st $${{n-\lambda_n+1}\over n}\lt {\delta\over 2}\ ; \forall n\ge m.$$

When $|A|$ stands for **Cardinality of A.**
 Then for any $n\ge m$ we have ,
$${1\over n}|\{k\in \mathbb N:k\le n\  satisfying\ D\}|={1\over n}|\{k\in \mathbb N:k\lt n-\lambda_n +1\ satisfying \ D\}|+{1\over n}|\{k\in \mathbb N:k\in I_n\ satisfying\ D\}|\\ \lt {{n-\lambda_n +1}\over n}+{1\over n}|\{k\in \mathbb N:k\in I_n\ satisfying\ D\}|\\ \lt {\delta \over 2}+ \color{fuchsia}{{1\over {\lambda_n}}|\{k\in \mathbb N:k\in I_n\ satisfying\ D\}|}$$

The $\color{fuchsia}{part}$ is what I cannot understand , how is that derives from the previous line $?$ This is the first problem . The second one is the next line that says :

Hence for $\delta \gt 0$ , we can say ,
$$\color{fuchsia}{\left\{n\in \mathbb N : {1\over n}|\{k\in \mathbb N : k\le n\ satisfying\ D\}|\ge \delta \right\}\\ \subset \left\{n\in \mathbb N : {1\over n}|\{k\in \mathbb N:k\in I_n\ satisfying\ D  \}|\ge {\delta \over 2} \right\}\bigcup \left\{1,2,3,....m\right\}}$$

How this follows from the previous segment $?$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Fuchsia? Really? It burns my eyes.

Comment: @ArtW : No. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, this is because $1\over n$ is always $\le$ than $1\over \lambda_n$ (since $\lambda_n\le n$).

Note, though, that your notation is really cumbersome: e.g. $\vert\{k\in\mathbb{N}: k\le n\}\vert$ is just $n$, and $\vert\{k\in\mathbb{N}: k\in I_n\}$ is just $\vert I_n\vert$.

This becomes an issue in your second question, where I'm almost certain something has gone wrong: the set on the left hand of the "$\subset$" is just $\{n: 1\ge\delta\}$, which is either all of $\mathbb{N}$ or $\emptyset$ depending on what $\delta$ is.

---

EDIT: OK, so first let's simplify your notation. Let $D_n=D\cap \{1, . . . , n\}$ and similarly $J_n=D\cap I_n$. Then what you want to show is: for $n>m$, if $\vert D_n\vert\over n$ is greater than $\delta$, then $\vert J_n\vert\over n$ is greater than $\delta\over 2$. (Do you see why?) Above, you showed that if $n>m$ then ${\vert D_n\vert\over n}<{\delta\over 2}+{\vert J_n\vert\over\lambda_n}$. So by combining inequalities, we get $${\delta}<{\vert D_n\vert\over 2}<{\delta\over 2}+{\vert J_n\vert\over 2},$$ so $\vert J_n\vert\over 2$ is greater than $\delta\over 2$. So we're done.

Comment: And for the second ?

Comment: It came from the $\lambda_{n+1}\le \lambda_n +1$ part , right ?

Comment: @user118494 Yes, $\lambda_{n+1}\le\lambda_n+1$ together with $\lambda_1=1$ implies $\lambda_n\le n$. As to the second part, I'm fairly certain that something got typed incorrectly; see my edit.

Comment: I am editing my question,Now that you said it , I realised that some modifications regarding the notations are required. kindly take a look .

Comment: @user118494 See my edit.